# Hide a parent view with child view reference

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

I was asked to hide a parent view with its child reference (IBOutlet).If this is possible then please give me a answer.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: We need information on how the view is set up. Where is the IBOutlet and what does it connect to?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
childView.superview?.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your parent View and Set `isHiddent` true. You can try something like this.

```
guard let parentView = childView.superview as? ParentType else { return }
parentView.isHidden = true
```